# Android BKS Tempering via Reverse Engineering

Tags: android, aws-sdk, bouncycastle

We are using aws client for our connection layer. aws-sdk is using "BKS" Keystore and writing it file into the file system.

Below is the class of sdk which is managing Keystore in file system.

https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-iot/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/iot/AWSIotKeystoreHelper.java

We are looking for one more layer of protection which will help us in protecting our Keystore on rooted devices. So we are looking for that solution which will help us in protecting our Private keys and client certs which reside in Keystore.

Comment: Read https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/dexguard

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya do you mean paid tool for dex protection? sorry if that is a case, we can't rely/trust any third party for securing our highly sensitive data

Comment: Also, aws-sdk write "BKS" keystore in file system at run time after signing certs with PrivateKey so dex protection won't help. As Keystore written in file system.